# List of default applications for a given android version

Tags: applications, stock-android

Is there a list for the stock applications (those who are installed by default with android), and libraries? for example: Atci_service, calendar, com.mediatek are they default applications? Or where there added by someone else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check on android.com, which contains the list of apps included with each version:

- [1.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-1.1.html#apps)
- [1.5](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-1.5.html#apps) (Cupcake)
- [1.6](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-1.6.html#apps) (Donut)
- [2.0](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.0.html#apps) (Eclair)
- [2.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.1.html#apps) (Eclair)

Unfortunately, they stopped that listing after Eclair (2.1). And of course each "ROM cook" might have added other apps (and [bloatware](/questions/tagged/bloatware)) to the list...